# Find the general solution by eigen value method

Tags: systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

Given the following system $ \ \vec{x'}=\begin{pmatrix}12 & 25 \\ 1 & 225 \end{pmatrix} \vec{x} $ .

Find the general solution  by eigen value method .

**Answer:**

The  coefficient matrix has the Eigen values $ \ 11.9 \ \ and \ \ 225.1 \ $ .

But I can not find the Eigen vectors from these Eigen values because substituting each Eigen value in the system

$ \begin{pmatrix}12-\lambda & 25 \\ 1 & 225-\lambda \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix}=0 $ ,

it  produces two different  homogeneous equations giving $ \ \vec{0} $ .

**Thus how can I find the Eigen vectors ? Any help ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eigenvalues are
$$\lambda_1=\frac{1}{2}(237+\sqrt{45469})$$
$$\lambda_1=\frac{1}{2}(237-\sqrt{45469})$$
Substituting into 
$$(A-I\lambda)x=0$$
yields a pair of eigenvectors
$$x_1=\left(\frac{1}{2}(-213+\sqrt{45469},1\right)$$
$$x_2=\left(\frac{1}{2}(-213-\sqrt{45469}),1\right)$$